# Receiving emails to raspberry pi and then sending to print?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, printing

Is it possible to wifi enable the Raspberry Pi so that it could receive emails? They are just photos automatically sent from my photo account, so there is no text. Then it needs to automatically send the images from the email over Bluetooth to a device that can print it out. (polaroid gl10)?

The aim is to:

1. Receive email
2. Send newest file/email to Bluetooth  printer device
3. Print photo
4. Delete that email
5. Wait for another email/start process again from 1

Comment: Would this email actually be on the Pi itself ? or are you planning on using something like gMail to receive the emails ?

Comment: I'd use [mailinator](http://mailinator.com/). It allows you to subscribe to an RSS feed of a public email address. Watching that feed for changes would be much simpler than setting up an email server yourself.

Comment: I suppose it would, although im trying to think of ways for this little printer and a pi to automatically print out photos everytime I take one and upload it. 
I had a look at mailinator but it wont allow attachments or photos. Watching an rss feed is a good idea but im not sure how the feed would update and send itself via bluetooth to a device/printer. I could just be looking at it in the most difficult way. Im using ifthisthenthat to send an email everytime a photo is uploaded to instagram.

Comment: Lawrence - Ill most likely use gMail to receive the emails then 'push' these to the pi

Comment: The best way is to install SMTP server on the Pi. Forward email to the Pi (redirect or gmail forwarding)(open port 25) and tell the SMTP server on the Pi to run a script on the email. You then need to make the script to extract attachments and send the files to the printer over Bluetooth. You can do this in any language you are comfortable with. (Python, C, C# with Mono, Java, etc) We are not going to do it for you, sorry. If you run into more problem we invite you back to ask more specific question.

Comment: I just wanted to see if there was a more defined method than what I listed. Ill have a go. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the Python `imaplib`. Here as an example of connecting to gmail (you need to enable imap in the gmail control panel)

```
import getpass, imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
M.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass())
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])
M.close()
M.logout()
```